# Hibernate - java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, object, exception, casting

I have strange problem which concerns getting objects from SQLLite DB. When I'am trying to get object from list I get following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to DataBase.Hibernate.Entities.Client.ClientEntity
```

Any suggestions?

**Mapping file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="DataBase.Hibernate.Entities.Client.ClientEntity" table="Clients">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the client detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="name" column="Name" type="string"/>
      <property name="surname" column="Surname" type="string"/>
      <property name="contact" column="Contact" type="string"/>
  </class>

  <sql-query name="ClientEntity.findByID">
    <![CDATA[
        select * from Clients AS c where c.ID =:id
    ]]>
   </sql-query>

   <sql-query name="ClientEntity.getAll">
    <![CDATA[
        select * from Clients
    ]]>
   </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ClientEntity class:**

```
package DataBase.Hibernate.Entities.Client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClientEntity implements Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String contact; 

    public ClientEntity(String name, String surname, String contact) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public ClientEntity() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

**Method for getting objects from table Clients**

```
HibernateManager hibernate = HibernateManager.beginWork();
List<ClientEntity> list = hibernate.getNamedQuery(
Queries.GET_CLIENT_BY_ID).setInteger(Columns.ID, aClientID).list();
hibernate.endWork();
```

**Queries.GET_CLIENT_BY_ID** is variable which contains name of "named query" from ClientEntity.hbm.xml file ("**ClientEntity.findByID**").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn HQL, and use it instead of using SQL. Your 2 queries should be HQL queries:

```
select c from ClientEntity c where c.id =:id
select c from ClientEntity
```

Note that the firsqt query is useless, since you just need to use

```
session.get(ClientEntity.class, id)
```

to get a client by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it. I have done small correction. But after all I have problem with Null Pointer Exception...

### [Project source](http://www55.zippyshare.com/v/98162245/file.html)

Problem occurs in class **T4esty** in method **listClients**.

Property **hibernate.connection.url** is not avaliable when program starts, but set "dynamically" after small initialization. Also data base is created each time program starts.